# How I can merge "changes" from two text files in one file, programmatically?

Tags: java, scala

## Use case

The requirement is to merge CHANGES from two different files in one file.
*This is not about JOINING two files end-to-end.*

Consider files **FILE_A**, **FILE_B** & **FILE_C**, respectively:

**FILE_A**

```
FUNCTION FUNCTION1
STATEMENT STATEMENT11
STATEMENT STATEMENT12
;

FUNCTION FUNCTION2
STATEMENT STATEMENT21
STATEMENT STATEMENT22
;
```

**FILE_B**

```
FUNCTION FUNCTION1
    STATEMENT STATEMENT11   #this is comment1
    STATEMENT STATEMENT12
;

FUNCTION FUNCTION2
    STATEMENT STATEMENT21   #this is comment2
    STATEMENT STATEMENT22
;
```

**FILE_C**

```
FUNCTION FUNCTION1
STATEMENT STATEMENT11
STATEMENT STATEMENT12
;

FUNCTION FUNCTION2
STATEMENT STATEMENT21
STATEMENT STATEMENT22
STATEMENT STATEMENT23
;
```

The important thing to notice here is that **FILE_A** & **FILE_C** are system-generated while **FILE_B** includes indentation corrections and comments made by the user.

The problem is that every time this file is system generated, we are losing the indentations and comments made by the user.

## Solution I propose:

After generating **FILE_C**, system should merge changes from **FILE_B** &  **FILE_C** into a new file, **FILE_D** which I call as *superimposing files*.

**FILE_D**

```
FUNCTION FUNCTION1
    STATEMENT STATEMENT11   #this is comment1
    STATEMENT STATEMENT12
;

FUNCTION FUNCTION2
    STATEMENT STATEMENT21   #this is comment2
    STATEMENT STATEMENT22
    STATEMENT STATEMENT23
;
```

But I am not sure how to achieve this programmitically!

Any suggestion on how to solve this problem is appreciated. I am trying to solve this problem in **Scala** though.

---

**Edited 1**

## What alternative approach could I employ to preserve indentations and comments?

The system takes care of preserving other changes besides indentations and comments, made by the user, such as, functions and statements but not indentations and comments. How to achieve the same? Please suggest?

*Please let me know if this is the right place for this question or this question needs to be expressed in a better way.*

Comment: Are indentations and comments the only changes the user can make?

Comment: No. He can also add functions, statements, etc.

Comment: You want to append two files data open the file in append mode and write it should work I think.

Comment: You want a merging functionality that many VersionControlSystems use. Maybe you could look there for an answer.

Comment: You might want to look at the program called `patch`, available on Linux systems. It can take a `diff` output (with context) and apply it to a file. It uses some amount of heuristics to find the best place to patch in the changes.

Comment: This whole question looks like an XY-problem. If you have to manually edit some configuration files on every build, then you should fix the build, instead of trying to automate the manual corrections. Inventing a CRDT specially for your particular configuration file seems like a seriously bad idea. Even if you get it to work somehow, it will probably be extremely brittle.

Comment: Other alternative is that you can write one java api or shell script to select the string **regex** pattern in File B(user edited) before comments, Then copy comment into separete string and Search for pattern in file c, find it and add the comment string To it. Use string regex pattern wisely, if not it picks some other lines.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known problem for generated configuration files. Trying to merge these files somehow is in my opinion the wrong approach, as it is also very error-prone. Even big applications like git do not merge multiple changes in one file (instead, you have to do it manually. It is called a merge conflict). Most approach this by adding the information `#DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - ANY CHANGES WILL BE OVERRIDEN` to the generated configuration file. The user is then instead meant to copy the file to another directory and make changes there.

#### Directory Structure

```
config
|
` - generated
|   |
|   `application.conf # Generate your config to this file
|
|
` - changes
    |
    `application.conf # Read your config from this file. If it doesn't exist, read config/generated/application.conf instead
```

Comment: Agreed! I have updated the question asking for an alternative way to preserve indentations and comments. Please suggest!

Comment: Well, this will preserve them, as you do not override any files, but implicitly ask the user to do it.

Comment: In that case I don't think this problem could be solved since we can't ask the user to do it as it defies the purpose of the system itself.

Comment: Can you instead suggest an alternative approach to preserve indentations and comments in a file? Surprise me.

Comment: I'm not sure where and when you want to "preserve" those. Either way, if there was a good solution for this, Git would probably have implemented this.